# CSS overlay does not work on mobiles

Tags: html, css

I use a code I found on the web to have a CSS overlay.
The overlay is used to display help to a graph.

On desktops it works great.

I can set the height so that all the text fits inside the overlay.

But if I look at it on a mobile phone the overlay seems to have a set height that I can't change.

Only about half of the text has a white background, and that makes it hard to read.

How can I change it so that mobile users also can read all the text?

The code is pasted below.
If you wish to test it on my webpage go to www.hoppvader.nu

But to be able to see this chart and the overlay you need to accept cookies and set some settings on the page.

The settings icon on top right, and set Visa lufttrycksstatistik to "Ja".

Accept cookies in the checkbox and create the cookie.

The cookie can later be removed on the same page but with the button on the right side (not visible if you don't have a cookie).

CSS:

```
    #overlay{ /* we set all of the properties for are overlay */
                height:800px;
                width:80%;
                margin:0 auto;
                background:white;
                color:black;
                padding:35px;
                position:absolute;
                top:5%;
                left:7%;
                z-index:1000;
                display:none;
                /* CSS 3 */
                -webkit-border-radius:10px;
                -moz-border-radius:10px;
                -o-border-radius:10px;
                border-radius:10px;
            }

            #mask{ /* create are mask */
                position:fixed;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
                z-index:500;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                display:none;
            }
            /* use :target to look for a link to the overlay then we find are mask */
            #overlay:target, #overlay:target + #mask{
                display:block;
                opacity:1;
            }
            .close{ /* to make a nice looking pure CSS3 close button */
                display:block;
                position:absolute;
                top:-20px;
                right:-20px;
                background:red;
                color:white;
                height:40px;
                width:40px;
                line-height:40px;
                font-size:35px;
                text-decoration:none;
                text-align:center;
                font-weight:bold;
                -webkit-border-radius:40px;
                -moz-border-radius:40px;
                -o-border-radius:40px;
                border-radius:40px;
            }
            #open-overlay{ /* open the overlay */
                padding:5px 5px;
                background:black;
                color:white;
                text-decoration:none;
                display:inline-block;
                margin:0px;
                -webkit-border-radius:10px;
                -moz-border-radius:10px;
                -o-border-radius:10px;
                border-radius:10px;
            }


HTML:
<a href='#overlay' id='open-overlay'><img src='../barchart.php?ICAO=ESNS'></img></a>
    <div id='overlay'>
                <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a>
                <div style='height:-5%'></div>
                <center><h2 style='font-size:35px'>Lufttryck</h2></center>
                Lufttrycket har stor betydelse för hur vädret kommer att bli.<br>
                Det finns många andra anledningar också förutom lufttrycket men nedan följer generella 'regler' för lufttrycksförändringar.<br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <p11>Lufttrycket ökar</p11><br>
                Om lufttrycket ökar men inte för snabbt (mindre än 1 hPa/h), tyder det på att vädret kommer att bli bättre.<br>
                Om lufttrycket ökar snabbt (mer än 1 hPa/h), tyder det på bättre väder på kort sikt men kan också betyda att en högtrycksstorm är på väg. <br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <p11>Lufttrycket sjunker</p11><br>
                Om lufttrycket sjunker konstant och långsamt (mindre än -1 hPa/h) kommer vädret troligtvis att försämras långsamt.<br>
                Om lufttrycket sjunker snabbt (mellan -1 till -2 hPa/h) kan ni räkna med starka vindar.<br>
                Om det sjunker mer än -2 hPa/h då kan ni räkna med mycket starka vindar.<br>
                <br>
                <br>
                <p11>Hur avläser jag diagrammet?</p11><br>
                Lufttrycket i värde skrivs ut ovanför var stapel.<br>
                Värdet under stapeln är när värdet uppmättes. Dagen står överst och tiden under.<br>
                Tänk på att lufttrycket varierar lite under en dag och behöver inte betyda väderförändringar.<br><br>
                Alla stationer uppdateras när någon av hoppvädersidorna visas.<br>
                Om en station inte visar några staplar alls beror det på att stationen inte varit igång sedan mätningarna började sparas.<br>
            </div>
            <div id='mask' onclick='document.location='#';'></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take out `height:100%` from your css styling `#overlay` and the div will adjust with its background to fit the contents when the window resizes.

snippet here

```css
#overlay{ /* we set all of the properties for are overlay */
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:white;
    color:black;
    padding:35px;
    position:absolute;
    top:5%;
    left:7%;
    z-index:1000;
    display:none;
    /* CSS 3 */
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

#mask{ /* create are mask */
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index:500;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
}
/* use :target to look for a link to the overlay then we find are mask */
#overlay:target, #overlay:target + #mask{
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
}
.close{ /* to make a nice looking pure CSS3 close button */
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:-20px;
    background:red;
    color:white;
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    font-size:35px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    -webkit-border-radius:40px;
    -moz-border-radius:40px;
    -o-border-radius:40px;
    border-radius:40px;
}
#open-overlay{ /* open the overlay */
    padding:5px 5px;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -o-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<a href='#overlay' id='open-overlay'><img src='../barchart.php?ICAO=ESNS'></img></a>
<div id='overlay'>
<a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a>
<div style='height:-5%'></div>
<center><h2 style='font-size:35px'>Lufttryck</h2></center>
Lufttrycket har stor betydelse för hur vädret kommer att bli.<br>
Det finns många andra anledningar också förutom lufttrycket men nedan följer generella 'regler' för lufttrycksförändringar.<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p11>Lufttrycket ökar</p11><br>
    Om lufttrycket ökar men inte för snabbt (mindre än 1 hPa/h), tyder det på att vädret kommer att bli bättre.<br>
    Om lufttrycket ökar snabbt (mer än 1 hPa/h), tyder det på bättre väder på kort sikt men kan också betyda att en högtrycksstorm är på väg. <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p11>Lufttrycket sjunker</p11><br>
    Om lufttrycket sjunker konstant och långsamt (mindre än -1 hPa/h) kommer vädret troligtvis att försämras långsamt.<br>
    Om lufttrycket sjunker snabbt (mellan -1 till -2 hPa/h) kan ni räkna med starka vindar.<br>
    Om det sjunker mer än -2 hPa/h då kan ni räkna med mycket starka vindar.<br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p11>Hur avläser jag diagrammet?</p11><br>
    Lufttrycket i värde skrivs ut ovanför var stapel.<br>
    Värdet under stapeln är när värdet uppmättes. Dagen står överst och tiden under.<br>
    Tänk på att lufttrycket varierar lite under en dag och behöver inte betyda väderförändringar.<br><br>
    Alla stationer uppdateras när någon av hoppvädersidorna visas.<br>
    Om en station inte visar några staplar alls beror det på att stationen inte varit igång sedan mätningarna började sparas.<br>
</div>
<div id='mask' onclick='document.location='#';'></div>
```

Comment: Why didn't I try that... 

Thank you!